# PHP login session state is not changing

Tags: php

I have 2 files, On my main index.php I have:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_session['login']=false;
??
```

I have another php file where i store the navbar, in this php file i have

```
   if ($_SESSION['login']==true) { ?>
    show this menu.. user is logged in.
   <?php }else { <?
    show this one, not logged in.
   <?php } ?>
```

in my login.php I simply have:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['login']=true;
```

so why is it that when i call the login.php file (on the click of a button) that session state isn't changed?

Comment: $_session != $_SESSION.  PHP variables are case sensitive.

Comment: `$_session` is a superglobal and MUST be in uppercase.

Comment: Other than the above, why are you declaring a php tag for EVERY SINGLE LINE?

Answer (score 1):

`$_session` is a superglobal and MUST be in uppercase.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

and having checked for errors would have thrown you something about it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

you also need to make sure that the session was started in all files using sessions.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

You also have 2x `??` which I don't if it's part of your real code.

If it is, then that needs to read as `?>`.

Sidenote:

It's always best to check if the session is set, rather then just checking if it's `true|false`.

I.e.:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login']==true)
```

or (not empty)

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login']==true)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, all files you are using $_SESSION you must insert before all code "session_start()"

Answer (score 0):

Superglobals in PHP must be written in uppercase. Therefore this should be in uppercase:

```
$_session['login']=false;
```

Like this:

```
$_SESSION['login']=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

well looks like i solved my problem.. one of those facepalm moments. I wasn't checking if the session had already been set and therefore i kept resetting it back to 0 when index.php refreshed. thanks for letting me know it's supposed to be in capitals, wasn't aware of that. so adding this to the top of my index.php solved it:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    $_SESSION['login']=0;
}

?>
```

Comment: something to which I had thought of even before seeing your answer ;-) just worded a bit differently.